# What is different between int main() and int main(void)?

Tags: c++

Can anyone help me with what is different between `int main()` and `int main(void)`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `(void)` as the single parameter in a C++ function is exactly equivalent to using `()`.

Although, stylistically `(void)` is to be discouraged.

Comment: Do we really need to answer such an obvious dupe?

Answer (score 0):

In C++, there is no difference. The difference only arises in C, where not explicitly mentioning `void` in the parameter list allows the function to be called with any number of parameters, while the second version only allows exactly 0 parameters.